# Can anyone suggest the best way to move a database from SQL Server 2008 to 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have database with a size of around 100GB in SQL Server 2008. I want to run this database in SQL Server 2005. Can anyone suggest the best way to move that database from SQL Server 2008 to 2005?

I have generated a script using the generate script wizard. The script file is around 25 GB large. So I ran the script from the command prompt using this command:

```
Sqlcmd -U sa -P **** -S 192.168.10.001\SQL2005 
       -i D:\dbRestore\Script.sql -a 32767 
       -o D:\dbRestore\ScriptError.txt
```

And I got the following errors:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'xxx' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
>
> Invalid object name 'data_set'
>
> Invalid column name 'benefit_contract_id'
>
> Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
>
> Must declare the scalar variable
>
> Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml or large user defined type columns.
>
> User or role 'tuser01' does not exist in this database.
>   Windows NT user or group 'xxx\SQL_QA' not found. Check the name again

Can anyone help me to solve these issues?

Comment: Why?  You can set the compatibility level to emulate SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Set database compatibility level to Sql Server 2005 (90)

```
ALTER DATABASE <your database_name>
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

Comment: I tried to change compatibility level to 90. But it shows error "Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, or 120" . Current compatibility level of my database is  is 120

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Check this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510680(v=sql.120).aspx), It contains backward compatibility table for various versions SQL Server.

Comment: This article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2015/02/04/beware-compatibility-level-90-is-no-longer-available-in-sql-2014.aspx) also contains useful information about compatibility levels.